# Solving an Improper Integral: $\int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-a\cdot r}dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have an improper integral as follows:

> $$\int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-a\cdot r}dr.$$

I try to evaluate it by parts and get $ [ -(\dfrac{r^2}{a} + \dfrac{2r}{a^2} + \dfrac{2}{a^3}) \cdot e^{-a \cdot r} ]^\infty_0 $, which leads me to nowhere.

According to the given solution, this integral can be solved like this:

$\int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-a\cdot r} = \dfrac{\delta^2}{\delta r^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-a\cdot r} = ... = \dfrac{2}{a^3} $

Which rule did they apply here (for the derivative)?

Comment: Your solution using integration by parts gives $$[ -(\dfrac{a \cdot r^2}{2} + \dfrac{r \cdot a^2}{2} + \dfrac{a^3}{4}) \cdot e^{-a \cdot r} ]^\infty_0
$$ I'm not sure why you don't use this since (for $a$ positive) there is no problem putting in the limits (for $r=0$ most terms vanish and for $r=\infty$ all terms vanish). For your second method you have $$I(a) = \int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-a\cdot r} \, dr$$ and then you look at $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \, a^2}$

Comment: The derivative in their solution should be with respect to $a$ and not $r$, to see it just swap integral and derivative, apply the derivative to the integrand, and you will get the starting integral back. Moreover, $a>0$ for the integral to be correct.

Comment: I still not quite understand the second method. Would you mind explaining or giving me one more tiny hint?

Comment: $dr$ or $da$ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, made a mistake for the second method (apologies): For the second method you have to consider $$I(a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-a\cdot r} \, dr$$ Then if you look at $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \, a^2} I(a)$ this is equal to the required integral. But you have $I(a)= \frac{1}{a}$ and you can easily work out $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \, a^2} \frac{1}{a}$. As an additional point, you can't really look at $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \, r^2} \int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-a\cdot r} \, dr$, since $r$ is an integration variable.

Comment: ooops, meant to be a comment, find it convenient to prepare as an answer since you can see what you are typing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint...if you evaluate the expression you found, rather than leading you "nowhere" you get the same answer as given in the alternative solution. This is because $$x^ne^{-x}\rightarrow0$$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Thank you, I see it now, Anyway, I'm actually more interested in the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Method 1*. One may integrate by parts twice as follows,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-a\cdot r}dr&=\left[ r^2\:\frac{e^{-a\cdot r}}{-a}\right]_0^\infty+\frac1a\int_0^\infty (2r)\: e^{-a\cdot r}dr
\\\\&=0+\frac{2}a\int_0^\infty r\: e^{-a\cdot r}dr
\\\\&=\frac{2}a\left(\left[ r\:\frac{e^{-a\cdot r}}{-a}\right]_0^\infty+\frac1a\int_0^\infty e^{-a\cdot r}dr\right)
\\\\&=\frac{2}a\left(0+\frac1a\cdot \frac1a\right)
\\\\&=\frac{2}{a^3}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used that, for any fixed real numbers $n$ and $a>0$,
$$
\lim_{r \to \infty}\left(r^n \cdot e^{-a\cdot r}\right)=0.
$$

*Method 2*. One may apply the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) twice (all conditions are OK here):
$$\frac{d}{da} \left ( \int_\alpha^\beta f(a,x) \,\mathrm{d}x \right )= \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\partial}{\partial a}f(a,x) \,\mathrm{d}x,$$
on the one hand,
$$\frac{d^2}{da^2} \left (\int_0^\infty e^{-a\cdot x} \,\mathrm{d}x \right )= \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}e^{-a\cdot x} \,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty x^2 \cdot e^{-a\cdot x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
on the other hand,
$$\frac{d^2}{da^2} \left (\int_0^\infty e^{-a\cdot x} \,\mathrm{d}x \right )= \frac{d^2}{da^2} \left (\frac1a\right )=\frac{2}{a^3}.$$